# spring boot updating parent record makes child records lose FK reference to null

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I've a very simple Parent-Child relation focusing that both parent and its many child record could be saved in one shot. I can do the Create operation successfully and record gets saved for both Parent and Child's records FK also gets set to newly created ParentID. But on Update operation the FK refernce get set to `null`.

I'm using SprinDataJPA, JpaRepository that powers the service classes for DAO operation.
Using `repo.save(entity)` method for both save and update.

Following are my entity classes `Question` can have 0 or many `PossibleOption`

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String text;
    private String shortText;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private List<PossibleOption> options; 
    }
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PossibleOption {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "key_field")
    private Integer key;
    @Column(name = "value_field")
    private String value;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;
    
}
```

Following is the comparison between the JSON being passed for POST and PUT requests
[image]

Comment: plesae show how you set fields of Questuon and PossibleOption

Comment: M using lombok. Getting Json data as POST n PUT request

Comment: show the codes please

Comment: I've shared the JSON data being passed for both POST and PUT requests